# Poll Graph API endpoint to Teams presence information

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am looking for MS Graph Subscription (webhook) for the users presence information (still in beta as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) but I can't find any as per the documentation on change notifications
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0
If there is change in user presence (e.g Available to Busy etc) a event has to be triggered. Is the only option to poll the endpoint? Any ideas?

Comment: which kind of notification you have to receive via webhook?

Comment: i mean outlook,ms calendar etc.

Comment: Users presence information from the endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get